# Git Bash (on windows) : color doesn't work

Tags: git, doctrine, mingw-w64

In my git bash (on windows 7). Color works. But when I use doctrine or composer install for example, color doesn't work and I can see `←[37;44m`

Look

```
←[37;44m                                             ←[39;49m
←[37;44m  Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator  ←[39;49m
←[37;44m                                             ←[39;49m
```

Why `\033` is remplaced by `←` ?

An idea?