# How to activate color in sub-shell?

Tags: bash, git-bash, mingw-w64

When I start git-bash I get colour output for `ls -l`

But when I enter a sub-shell the colour does not work anymore: see red rectangle in the screenshot

[image]

Any ideas how to get colours working?

I have also tried to set some env-vars, but none work:

```bash
export COLOR=1
export CLI_COLOR=1
export LS_COLORS=1
```

This post is maybe related (but has now answer): [Git Bash (on windows) : color doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620536/git-bash-on-windows-color-doesnt-work)

Comment: check if its the `.bash_profile` vs. `.bashrc` case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940957/900078

Comment: @pynexj yes, this seems related: when I start `bash --login` colour also works in the subshell. When I start `bash`  and then `source /etc/profile` it also works. But how can I make it work in a script? e.g. execute `./script.bash` and call `( ls -l)` in the script

Comment: for running jest tests, we can pass the cmd-line parameter `--colors`: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/809